# Flutter: Only static members can be accessed in initializers on button press

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({this.auth, this.onSignedOut});

  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;

  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  void signOut() async {
    try {
      await widget.auth.signOut();
      widget.onSignedOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Which is trigged on a button press:

```dart
Container(
      child: new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text('Sign Out'),
          onPressed: signOut,
      ),
    )
```

However, I get this error by `onPressed: signOut`:
`Only static members can be accessed in initializers.`

I would like it so that that function - `signOut()` is called on the button press to run the code inside it. Is there any way I can do so? I think it has to do with how I am initilising the `auth` and `onSignedOut` methods.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is this your actual code?  Did you omit anything?  Usually that error message is from doing something like `class Foo { int someMember = someValue; }` and `someValue` isn't static (i.e., not known at compilation time).  Have you tried running `flutter analyze` on your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
Container(
      child: new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text('Sign Out'),
          onPressed: signOut,
      ),
    )
```

in class body declaration, you have 2 ways to solve it.

1. Make `signOut()` method `static`
2. Use above widget inside a method say inside `build`

   ```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     var container = Container(
       child: new RaisedButton(
         child: new Text('Sign Out'),
         onPressed: signOut,
       ),
     );

     return container;
   }
   ```

---

**Update**

[This](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) is a very basic example. So, to make it easy, they used `List<Widgets>`, I have updated this example with mine, you can see how you can use `_getWidget()` method to solve the same example.

```
int _selectedIndex = 0;
static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
Widget _getWidget(int index) {
  switch(index) {
    case 0: return Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    );

    case 1:
      return Text(
        'Index 1: Business',
        style: optionStyle,
      );

    case 2:
      return Text(
        'Index 2: School',
        style: optionStyle,
      );
  }
  return Container();
}

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample')),
    body: Center(child: _getWidget(_selectedIndex)),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.business),
          title: Text('Business'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.school),
          title: Text('School'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Making the method `static` leads to `Instance members can't be accessed from a static method.` Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: I don't have that code inside the `build` method as it is inside a widget outside of it. Are there any other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: If widget are not linked (like parent children) you should use a function callback

Comment: I am using this example - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html The widget list outside the build method is where the button is

Comment: @Saret how can I do that?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad your anwser is the right solution. clear and clean.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot.